# wso2 Enabling Notifications for User Operations

Tags: email, templates, server, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

we are trying to set Enabling Notifications for User Operations using following resource  https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Enabling+Notifications+for+User+Operation the document on wso2 site.

I done the changes required but still getting error template not found, so any one know in which format required for mail template.

Added this line to <PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/identity/msg-mgt.properties

```
**module.name.1=email
email.subscription.1=userOperation
email.subscription.userOperation.template=/home/user/Desktop/johnsmith (If you are using windows machine the path would be C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\johnsmith)
email.subscription.userOperation.salutation=Admin
email.subscription.userOperation.subject=User operation change information
email.subscription.userOperation.endpoint.1=privateMail
email.subscription.userOperation.endpoint.privateMail.address=receiver@gmail.com
email.subscription.userOperation.endpoint.privateMail.salutation=Admin private mail
email.subscription.userOperation.endpoint.privateMail.subject=User operation change information to private mail**
```

what kind of filetype or how to write template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be the path to your email template. I added it as follows.

```
email.subscription.userOperation.template=/Users/tommy/wso2is-5.11.0/repository/template1.xml
```

Here I added the file as a XML but just added the template as follows.

```
Hi {salutation}

This is a test mail to your private mail. The operation that occurred was: {operation}
```

Also you can add a `txt` file.

Comment: HI @Sominda but stiill unbale to get notification on mail when user operation events like user create app, subscribe plan, delete app any. Is their any additional settings required. using wso2 4.1.

Comment: Hi @VikasPatil `user create app, subscribe plan, delete app` are not user operations. User operations are when u do some changes to users profile

Comment: Hi @Sominda is their any way to get me and user notification by mail if user subscribe plan, change in teir, or quota exceeded by api hit like

Comment: @VikasPatil seems like these are not events managed by the Identity Server. Therefore I believe this cannot be done. But if these actions update a claim in the user profile then it will consider as a user operation event and you will be able to get notification.

Comment: Hi @Sominda Can we configure api alert in wso24.1 without using choreo analytics or is ther any free analytics portal for same like wso2 3.0

Comment: @VikasPatil you can write a custom event listener add send emails depending on that. AFAIK this requires some effort as this may not be straight forward.